# running z3 on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, z3, z3py

I'd like to find a pure-python z3 package that will help me to run z3 in google app engine.  I've run the following python test locally and it runs:

```
from z3 import *

    x = Real('x')
    y = Real('y')
    s = Solver()
    s.add(x + y > 5, x > 1, y > 1)
    print s.check()
    print s.model()
```

But it needs these files to make it work: z3.pyc, z3consts.pyc, z3core.pyc, z3printer.pyc, z3types.pyc, libz3.dylib.  I got those files by building z3 from a download from the z3 codeplex site.

So with these files in a 'lib' folder inside my app id folder, I tried the following adaption of main.py (the 'hello world' program provided by google):

```
import webapp2
from random import randint
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
from z3 import *

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        x = Real('x')
        y = Real('y')
        s = Solver()
        s.add(x + y > 5, x > 1, y > 1)
        self.response.write(s.check())
        self.response.write(s.model())
        self.response.write('Hello world! '+str(randint(7,14)))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

This code run in the app engine launcher provides me with a blank white page and no error messages.

If I comment out all of the z3-related code, I get a hello world message, as expected.

Note: I have read article 14850853 about how to include 3rd party libraries, and have successfully tested it using BeautifulSoup.  My question is about the availability of a pure python z3 library.

From google's documentation about sandboxing, I'm pretty sure that the *.pyc files are okay, but I think that the (16MB) libz3.dylib that those files need to work is not pure python.  Does a pure python version of z3 exist, or is there some other way to use z3 on app engine that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pure Python version of Z3. All API's for Z3, including the Python API, are built on top of the C API and libz3.dll/.so/.dylib is native code. I'm not sure that it would work with the Google App Engine, but in the past I had success with saving libz3.dll in a blob in an SQL database and when my application starts, it gets it from the database and loads it.

I'm not sure what app you're planning to develop, but please do have a quick look at the license of Z3 to make sure everything's OK in that regard.

Comment: So there is no pure python Z3.  To clarify, in what context did you have success loading libz3.dll from a blob?  I'm guessing it was some other SaaS context similar to Google App Engine.

Comment: It wasn't directly an app engine, but the Azure cloud which at that time didn't support native code deployment. Not sure what underlies the Google App Engine, it might be trickier than that.